# How open Firebase Auth UI as first activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using Firebase Auth UI, so i use `startActivityForResult`.

I call the method mentioned from an activity A, and the login screen is displayed correctly.

The problem is that the previous activity (activity A) is shown for a few seconds before calling the mentioned method, which is not what is desired, in addition when you press the back button, you can see the activity A.

```
startActivityForResult(
    // Get an instance of AuthUI based on the default app
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAuthMethodPickerLayout(buildMethodPickerLayout())
            .setAvailableProviders(getAuthProviders())
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setTheme(R.style.AppThemeFirebaseAuth)
            .build(),

    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

I know that I can use onActivityResult to exit the application when it goes back, but this does not solve the first problem, I also wanted to know a cleaner option.

I would like to show my Login layout as the first screen.

Comment: Hvae you tried to use a splash screen?

Comment: Yes, thats my temporaly solution.

Comment: That's the most convenient way of solving this. This is what I have also used in one of my [repos](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseapp/SplashActivity.java) ;)

Comment: @AlexMamo I will check it now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you set your styles like this you won't be able to see blinking/animation of Firebase AuthUI activity on start and on exit - you will see Login layout as the first screen.

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/appBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
```

```
    <style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/appBackground</item>
    </style>
```

But the best option would be to build a custom login screen to not use the Firebase activity.